# Uninstall a software which was setup with wine

Tags: wine, vmware

I have installed *VMWare Workstation 12 pro(Windows 10)* in Ubuntu using Wine.
Now I want to uninstall VMware but couldn't find any way to do so.
How can I uninstall VMWare and how can I uninstall wine itself?
**N.B.:- sudo-apt remove wine and sudo apt-purge wine is not working.**

Comment: "Not working" is a bit broad... exactly what error is the computer throwing when you run `sudo apt remove wine`?

Comment: And furthermore, typically you don't have to run `sudo apt remove wine`, you have to put the version in there; ie., `sudo apt remove wine1.6`, since various versions of wine have different package names.  Also, the dashes in the commands you posted will totally mess it up; I presume that you did not put them in the terminal command?

Comment: @anonymous2 it's saying virtual packages like 'wine' can't be removed

Comment: it can't find such version. I have wine 4.0 installed

Comment: Please edit your question to clearly explain the steps you followed to install VMWare and Wine. Links to instructions you followed would be very helpful. apt can uninstall only *deb packages* - it you installed some other way (and there are many), apt cannot remove it.